Task.Delay() is 10x slower in docker linux than in windows
I am struggling with a timing issue I have in Docker
Here is my test code:
    using System.Diagnostics;


    DisplayStopWatchResolution();

    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    //begin the test
    while (true)
    {
        timer.Restart();
        timer.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(1);
        await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Task time {timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}");
    }

    static void DisplayStopWatchResolution()
    {
        if (Stopwatch.IsHighResolution)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operations timed using the system's high-resolution performance counter.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operations timed using the DateTime class.");
        }

        long frequency = Stopwatch.Frequency;
        Console.WriteLine("  Timer frequency in ticks per second = {0}",
            frequency);
        long nanosecPerTick = (1000L * 1000L * 1000L) / frequency;
        Console.WriteLine("  Timer is accurate within {0} nanoseconds",
            nanosecPerTick);
    }

What I want is for the system to wait around 1ms.
However I am getting these results:

Windows | Timer is accurate within 100 nanoseconds:

await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false); is roughly  1.942 ms (acceptable)
Thread.Sleep(1) is again roughly 1.942ms (acceptable)


Linux (ubuntu on WSL using docker) | Timer is accurate within 1 nanoseconds:

await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false) is roughly 10 ms (my bad case)
Thread.Sleep() is 1.0712ms (really good)


Linux (ubuntu running the exe):

await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false); is roughly  1.942 ms (acceptable)
Thread.Sleep(1) is again roughly 1.942ms (acceptable)



I need to use docker and would prefer to use Task.Delay() as to not block the thread however with the performance being 10x what is should b, it's not really an option.
My question is how to fix Task.Delay() under Docker linux to not be so slow.
Thank you
NOTE:
As requested, here is a github link with the code and docker files
https://github.com/anthonyMc11/TaskProblem/tree/main

could you post your project to github so we could reproduce it? With the minimum required code and your dockerfile.

@zsolt now posted with a raised bounty

since Task.Delay() is dependent on the system clock, make sure that your Docker container is running with access to a high-resolution clock. Docker's default configurations may sometimes limit the resolution of timers due to the container environment. you can check the resolution inside the container by running:
cat /proc/timer_list, please check in both windows and linux container and check if its same.

@0xn0b174 thanks for your interest! I print out the timer frequency when the project loads. Interestingly, the docker timer reports to be more accurate than on windows (1ns vs 100ns). Would this match what you would expect?

This is not the intended use case for Task.Delay(). There is no guarantee that the awaitable will return control to the task immediately once the delay has elapsed. That's not how cooperative concurrency works (ie. asynchronous). It depends entirely on what other tasks are running and how frequently they cede control of the event loop. Task.Delay() is for retying a bit of code, but backing off a bit so as not to overload the resource you are trying to use (like an HTTP server). It is not for fine-grained time synchronisation.
If you want to give other tasks a chance to execute before continuing in a busy loop then use await Task.Yield(). This will allow other tasks to execute (if they exist and are ready to execute), otherwise control is returned to the task immediately.

Thanks for your time and comment. I don't think Task.Yield would suit my use case and also does not explain why the thread management is so poor under docker, which was my question.

You're almost certainly running WSL 2, which runs your linux inside a docker container of a linux running on a virtual machine inside windows. So you're getting all the overhead that comes with that. You're going through a linux system call that then has translated to the equivalent windows system call(s). System calls are expensive to begin with, and you're getting double the pain because of the VM.

thanks @Dunes for taking the time to respond. My first theory was the number of layer of complexity I'd added to this, however it does not explain why  Thread.Sleep can perform 10x better in these conditions. There is no CPU or thread contention, this is the only code running which means there is something wrong with either docker or the image. What is confusing me is the 2 method perform consistently the same under windows and WSL2 linux directly, but under docker one is 10x slower with the same over heads.

I've taken a look at this question and it intrigued me to do some researching and this what I found about the WSL, Task.Delay() and Thread.Sleep() :
A: What is? :
# What is Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay() and their differences?
Thread.Sleep():
is a synchronous and which puts threads to sleep and directly interacts with the system scheduler.
Task.Delay():
The Task.Delay() is an asynchronous that relies SynchronizationContext or TaskScheduler and .NET runtime’s task management which adds task queuing, async/await mechanics, and cooperative multitasking.
# Asynchronous and Synchronous  : What is Asynchronous and Synchronous?
Asynchronous:
is a non-blocking architecture, so the execution of one task isn’t dependent on another. Tasks can run simultaneously.
Synchronous:
is a blocking architecture, so the execution of each operation depends on completing the one before it. Each task requires an answer before moving on to the next iteration.
More to read:
1. Asynchronous vs synchronous execution. What is the
difference?
2. https://code-maze.com/csharp-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay/#:~:text=Delay()%3F-,Task.,without%20blocking%20the%20calling%20thread.
B: What is the difference between WSL and Linux? :



feature
WSL
Linux




kernel
native Linux kernel
real Linux kernel inside a lightweight VM


performance
direct hardware interaction, highest performance
slight overhead due to virtualization, but generally good


file system
direct access to ext4, XFS, btrfs, etc.
virtual ext4 file system in a VHD, cross-access with windows


Resource
full access and control over CPU, memory, I/O
Hyper-V manages resources, limited by host OS


networking
native Linux networking
virtual networking, some overhead


use case
full-fledged Linux OS for all use cases
development-focused Linux environment on Windows


boot Control
full boot and kernel control
fast boot, limited to custom kernels supported by WSL2



Links:
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL): what can't I do with the Ubuntu application for Microsoft Windows?
WSL Limitations:  and 2
C: What might have caused the problem? or what is the problem ?
1:
From the some of the differences that we see between Linux and WSL we can see that Linux has direct Access to file systems, full access and control over Resources such as memory CPU  etc. which might gives it a hand to be faster than WSL that need to go through some process to get to them in this situation as I explained before the  could be bypassing these mechanisms and interacting more directly with the Linux kernel's scheduler than the Task.Delay(), which might explain why it Thread.Sleep() perform better
2:
There could be an additional overhead or timer precision issues because of the VM layer since WSL runs a Linux kernel inside a VM
3:
The precision of the timer can be different from Linux especially if there are limits to high-resolution timers.
Solutions:
1:
You can either create your own custom TaskScheduler or continue using the Thread.Sleep() which could Effect the scalability of your project
2:
Optimize Docker CPU shares and limits with: docker run --cpus="1.5" mycontainer or use the --privileged which gives you  direct access to the hosts hardware and resources
3
You can try using an alternative delay mechanisms from Task.Delay() such as using System.Threading.Timer

hope this might help or get you a little bit closer to your answer

Thanks for your verbose answer.
You answer is also around the difference between linux and WSL, and that is not where my issue lies. If I run the dll directly in WSL, it works at the 1ms I'd expect.
I have added a docker-compose to the github project, showing that even when run in privilege mode, the issue persists, the same occurs when I set cpus.
It's when ran in a docker container (on WSL or raw linux) that this issue occurs.
